# With Celery Canvas, what is the difference between chord() and chain(group(), task)

Tags: python, celery, celery-canvas

We're implementing a workflow with Celery. First we need to run some tasks in parallel, and when they are all finished we need to run a single task.

It seems we can use chord, or group and chain:

```
chord(tasks, task)
```

vs

```
group(tasks) | task
```

What is the exact difference between those two? They seem to do the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Canvas docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives) say:

> Chaining a group together with another task will automatically upgrade it to be a chord:
>
> ```
>  >>> c3 = (group(add.s(i, i) for i in xrange(10)) | xsum.s())
> >>> res = c3()
> >>> res.get()
> 90
> ```

Comment: Not sure why this is upvoted or accepted. It doesn't answer the question. Still not clear what the difference is here.

Answer (score 3):

From Canvas documentation:

- **group**

The group primitive is a signature that takes a list of tasks that should be applied in parallel.

- **chain**

The chain primitive lets us link together signatures so that one is called after the other, essentially forming a chain of callbacks.

- **chord**

A chord is just like a group but with a callback. A chord consists of a header group and a body, where the body is a task that should execute after all of the tasks in the header are complete.